# Вывод в html двумерного массива из js

Tags: javascript, html

Пока плохо разбираюсь в js, не подскажете как реализовать это задание? Или объяснить написанное в задании. По заданию, у меня есть двумерный массив js (часть его ниже), и его нужно представить в виде таблицы:

[image: Оформленный пример одной строки из массива]

Помогите с реализацией последних пунктов, никак не могу понять[image: Задание]

Вот пока всё что я сделала:

```js
/**  Информация о государствах мира **/
var about = ["Государство", "Столица", "Континент", "Часть света", "Разница во времени",
  "Денежная единица", "Географические объекты", "Литературные произведения",
  "Исторические события"
];

var countries = [
  ["Италия", "Рим", "Евразия", "Европа", -2, "итальянская лира", ["Альпы", "Пальмария", "Апеннинский полуостров", "Комо", "Тальяменто"],
    [
      ["Джованни Верга", "Жизнь среди полей", 1880],
      ["Анна Виванти", "Цирцея", 1912],
      ["Джузеппе Понтиджа", "Рождённые дважды", 2000]
    ],
    {
      "1882": "избирательная реформа",
      "1945": "антифашистское восстание, 18-28 апреля"
    }
  ],
  ["Франция", "Париж", "Евразия", "Европа", -1, "евро", ["Эндр", "Пиренеи", "Луара", "Альпы", "Бискайский залив"],
    [
      ["Александр Дюма", "Граф Монте-Кристо", 1845],
      ["Жюль Габриэль Верн", "Завещание чудака", 1900],
      ["Луи Анри Буссенар", "Капитан Сорви-голова", 2001],
      ["Морис Самюэль Роже Шарль Дрюон", "Тисту — мальчик с зелеными пальцами", 1957]
    ],
    {
      "1572": "Варфоломеевская ночь",
      "1648": "Вестфальский мир",
      "1914": "Марнское сражение, 5-12 сентября"
    }
  ],
  ["Швейцария", "отсутствует", "Евразия", "Европа", -1, "Швейцарский франк", ["Бильское озеро", "Рейхенбахский водопад", "Альпы", "Алечский ледник"],
    [
      ["Иоханна Спири", "Хайди: годы странствий и учёбы", 1880],
      ["Герман Гессе", "Игра в бисер", 1942],
      ["Макс Фриш", "Homo Фабер", 1957],
      ["Мелинда Надь Абонджи", "Голуби взлетают", 2010]
    ],
    {
      "1291": "основание Швейцарии",
      "1844": "начало работы первой железнодорожной линией"
    }
  ],
  ["Венгрия", "Будапешт", "Евразия", "Европа", -1, "Венгерский форинт", ["Геллерт", "Карпаты", "Веленце", "Мезёфёльд"],
    [
      ["Янош Бачаньи", "Мужество венгров", 1785],
      ["Аттила Бартиш", "Спокойствие", 2001],
      ["Ийеш Дьюла", "Двое мужчин", 1950]
    ],
    {
      "1222": "подписание Эндре II «Золотой буллы»",
      "1867": "Коронование Франца-Иосифа в Будапеште по старым обычаям, 8 июня"
    }
  ],
  ["Румыния", "Бухарест", "Евразия", "Европа", 0, "Румынский лей", ["Олт", "Трансильванское плато", "Карпаты", "Медвежья пещера", "Бабеле"],
    [
      ["Михаил Садовяну", "Золотая ветвь", 1933],
      ["Мирча Элиаде", "Изабель и воды дьявола", 1930]
    ],
    {
      "1881": "Румыния была провозглашена королевством",
      "1990": "первые свободные президентские и парламентские выборы",
      "2004": "Румыния стала членом НАТО"
    }
  ],
  ["Япония", "Токио", "Евразия", "Азия", 6, "японская иена", ["Фудзияма", "Сакурадзима", "Абукума"],
    [
      ["Сюсаку Эндо", "Море и яд", 1958],
      ["Юдзо Ямамото", "Профессор Цумура", 1919],
      ["Марико Хасиока", "Аут", 1997]
    ],
    {
      "1872": " отменена сложного и строгого сословного деления",
      "1904": "японский флот атаковал русскую эскадру в Порт-Артуре",
      "1941": "атака на Пёрл-Харбор"
    }
  ],
  ["Афганистан", "Кабул", "Евразия", "Азия", 1.5, "афгани", ["Намакзар", "Дашти-Марго", "Фарахруд", "Гиндукуш"],
    [
      ["Гуль Пача Ульфат", "Голос сердца", 1962],
      ["Абдуррауф Бенава", "Горестные размышления", 1957],
      ["Махмуд-бек Тарзи", "Путешествия через три континента за 29 дней", 1914]
    ],
    {
      "1973": "провозглашение Республики, 17 июля",
      "2004": "новая Конституция и проведены первые президентские выборы"
    }
  ],
  ["Индия", "Нью-Дели", "Евразия", "Азия", 2.5, "Индийская рупия", ["Ганг", "Гуру-Сикар", "Дудхсагар", "Цо-Морари", "Деканские траппы"],
    [
      ["Арундати Рой", "Бог мелочей", 1997],
      ["Хушвант Сингх", "Поезд в Пакистан", 1956]
    ],
    {
      "1857": "Восстание Сипаев",
      "1617": "Британская Ост-Индская компания получила право торговать с Индией",
      "1948": "Операция «Поло»",
      "1986": "архитектурное наследие Хампи включено в список Всемирного наследия"
    }
  ],
  ["Бразилия", "Бразилиа", "Южная Америка", "Америка", -6, "риал", ["Тапажос", "Пантанал", "пампа", "Сейшас", "Параноа"],
    [
      ["Лима Баррето", "Жалкий конец Поликарпо Кваресма", 1911],
      ["Эрику Верисиму", "Происшествие в Антаресе", 1971],
      ["Шику Буарки", "Будапешт ", 2003],
      ["Жоаким Мануэл ди Маседу", "Смуглянка", 1844]
    ],
    {
      "1888": "Золотой закон об отмене рабства в Бразилии, 13 мая",
      "1935": "вооружённое выступление бразильских коммунистов и тенентистов"
    }
  ],
  ["Канада", "Оттава", "Северная Америка", "Америка", -7, "канадский доллар", ["Фанди", "Подкова", "Элсмир", "Невольничье озеро", "Оттава"],
    [
      ["Филип Майкл Ондатже", "Английский пациент", 1992],
      ["Маргарет Этвуд", "Up In The Tree", 1978]
    ],
    {
      "1608": "основание города Квебек",
      "1838": "Битва за ветряную мельницу",
      "1867": "Канада получила право формировать собственное правительство"
    }
  ],
  ["Аргентина", "Буэнос-Айрес", "Южная Америка", "Америка", -6, "аргентинское песо", ["Охос-дель-Саладо", "Огненная земля", "Пампа", "Лагунас-де-Гуанакаче"],
    [
      ["Хорхе Луис Борхес", "Фунес памятливый", 1942]
    ],
    {
      "1912": "закон о всеобщем избирательном праве",
      "1871": "Завоевание пустыни",
      "1810": "Аргентинская война за независимость"
    }
  ],
  ["Колумбия", "Богота", "Южная Америка", "Америка", -8, "колумбийское песо", ["Кристобаль-Колон", "Магдалена", "Каука", "Анды", "Льянос"],
    [
      ["Рафаэль Помбо", "Флибустьеры", 1856],
      ["Хосе Эустасио Ривера", "Вихрь", 1924],
      ["Лаура Рестрепо", "Леопард на солнце", 1993]
    ],
    {
      "1916": "обнаружены богатейшие запасы нефти",
      "1549": "образование королевской аудиенсии и канцелярии Санта-Фе де Боготы",
      "1886": "принята консервативная конституция"
    }
  ],
  ["Англия", "Лондон", "", "", -3, "фунт стерлингов", ["Тис", "Белые клифы Дувра", "Саут-Даунс", "Скофелл-Пайк"],
    [
      ["Майн Рида", "Огненная земля", 1883],
      ["Уильям Шекспир", "Ромео и Джульетта", 1595],
      ["Оскар Уайльд", "Портрет Дориана Грея", 1891],
      ["Джонатан Свифт", "Путешествия в некоторые удалённые страны мира в четырёх частях: сочинение Лемюэля Гулливера, сначала хирурга, а затем капитана нескольких кораблей", 1726]
    ],
    {
      "1701": "Акт о престолонаследии",
      "1455": "начало войны Алой и Белой розы",
      "1215": "Великая хартия вольностей"
    }
  ],
  ["Мексика", "Мехико", "Южная Америка", "Америка", -9, "мексиканское песо", ["Попокатепетль", "Калифорния", "Эль-Вискаино", "Сонора", "Чапала", "Гуадалупе", "Пещера Ласточек"],
    [
      ["Октавио Пас", "Salamandra", 1962],
      ["Амадо Нерво", "Недвижная возлюбленная", 1922],
      ["Карлос Фуэнтес", "Смерть Артемио Круса", 1962],
      ["Хуан Рульфо", "Педро Парамо", 1955]
    ],
    {
      "1810": "Мексиканская война за независимость",
      "1536": "открытие коллегиума Санта-Крус де Тлателолько",
      "2006": "Революция кактусов"
    }
  ]
];


function makeTableFromCountry(country) {
  var i = 0;
  tab = '<table width = 100%>';
  // 
  tab += '<tr>';
  tab += '<td><h1>' + country[0] + ' - ' + country[1] + '</h1></tr>';
  tab += '</tr>';

  tab += '<tr><td>';
  tab += '<table width=70%>';
  for(i = 2; i <= 5; i++){
    tab += '<tr><td><i>' + about[i] + '</i></td><td>' + country[i] + '</td></tr>';
}
  tab += '</table>'
  tab += '</td></tr>';

  tab += '<tr><td>';
  tab += '<table>';

  tab += '</table>';
  tab += '</td></tr>';

  tab += '<tr><td><p>' + about[8] + '</p></td></tr>';

  tab += '<tr><td><table>';

  var i;
  //console.log(country.lenght);
  for (i = 0; i < country[8].lenght; i++) {
    tab += '<tr>' + country[8][i] + '</tr>';
  }
  //
  tab += '</table>';
  return tab;
}

qwerty = countries.map(makeTableFromCountry);
qwerty.forEach(function(info, i, arr) {
  document.body.innerHTML += info + "</br>";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Лабораторная работа №3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Информация о государствах</h1>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function outArrayData(data){
      var result = "";
        data.forEach(function(listItem) {
        result += "<li>" + listItem + "</li>";
    });
    return result;
}

function objectAsTable(historyObject) {
    var historyDates = Object.keys(historyObject);
    var tableLength = historyDates.length;
  var result = "";
  for(i = 0; i < tableLength; i++){
    var currentKey = historyDates[i];
    result += "<td><b>" + currentKey + "</b> " + historyObject[currentKey] + "</td>";
  }
  return result;
}

function makeTableFromCountry(country) {
  var i = 0;
  tab = '<table width = 100%>';
  // 
  tab += '<tr>';
  tab += '<td><h1>' + country[0] + ' - ' + country[1] + '</h1></tr>';
  tab += '</tr>';

  tab += '<tr><td>';
  tab += '<table width=70%>';
  for(i = 2; i <= 7; i++){
    switch (i) {
        case 6:
        //объекты
        tab += '<tr><td><i>' + about[i] + '</i></td><td><ol>' + outArrayData(country[i]) + '</ol></td></tr>';
        break;
        case 7:
        //произведения
        tab += '<tr><td><i>' + about[i] + '</i></td><td><ol>' + outArrayData(country[i]) + '</ol></td></tr>';
        break;
      default:
        tab += '<tr><td><i>' + about[i] + '</i></td><td>' + country[i] + '</td></tr>';
    }
    }
  tab += '</table>'
  tab += '</td></tr>';

  tab += '<tr><td>';
  tab += '<table>';

  tab += '</table>';
  tab += '</td></tr>';

  tab += '<tr><td><b>' + about[8] + '</b></td></tr>';

  tab += '<tr><td><table>';

  tab += '<tr>' + objectAsTable(country[8]) + '</tr>';
  //
  tab += '</table>';
  return tab;
}

qwerty = countries.map(makeTableFromCountry);
qwerty.forEach(function(info, i, arr) {
  document.body.innerHTML += info + "</br>";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/avr6pm9f/16/